# New Server 2012 with Exchange 2016 VM setup

Tags: exchange

I have experience with SBS and have been using 2012 for a while now, however never set up Exchange outside of an SBS box before.

So we have Server 2012r2 and Hyper-V role installed, on that will be one Virtual Machine as 2012r2 Domain controller/Active directory, second VM will be Exchange 2016.

My question is how will the exchange VM link to the Domain controller VM?
I have looked at this guide https://prajwaldesai.com/step-by-step-guide-to-install-exchange-server-2016/ but nothing about them being on different VM's, is it as simple as joining the Exchange VM to the domain?
Thanks all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To implement an Exchange 2016 Server to an existing Domain you need to do the following:

1. Join the OS for the Exchange Server to the domain
2. [Install the PreRequisites](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb691354(v=exchg.160).aspx#ADPrep)
3. [Extend the Active Directory Schema with Exchange properties (done via Exchange installer)](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb125224(v=exchg.160).aspx). You need to be member of Schema Admins and Enterprise Admins. *Keep noted that you should remove yourself from the Schema Admins group once you finish that task to prevent the Schema from any damage.*
4. [Install MS Exchange](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa998619(v=exchg.160).aspx)
5. Configure it

Comment: Yes MS provide a good documentation about the needed step (see links above). Wouldn´t use something else. By the way I would NEVER install an Exchange on an Domain Controller (MS also do not really support that).

Answer (score 0):

@BastianW steps are correct once you get the two VMs on the same network. Make sure the two VMs are on the same virtual switch or are on virtual switched that can communicate with each other.

If these are to be production VMs then they will probably need to be on the same External Virtual Switch.